# query gives an error saying there's an issue with converting a value to integer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, left-join

I have a query where I do multiple joins to get the text values for some of my fields. The problem is I keep getting an error stating that

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1774.14 ' to data
>   type int.

Below is my query...

```
SELECT t1.changedon as [Changed On], t1.fldname as [Field Name],   
CASE WHEN (t1.Fldname='LastKnownProvider' and t1.oldValue > 1000) THEN coalesce((t4.ProviderName + ' (' + t4.ProviderAddress + ', ' + t4.ProviderCity + ')'),cast(t1.oldvalue as varchar))  ELSE coalesce(t2.label,cast(t1.oldvalue as varchar)) END as [Old Value],   
CASE WHEN (t1.Fldname='LastKnownProvider' and t1.newValue > 1000) THEN coalesce((t5.ProviderName + ' (' + t5.ProviderAddress + ', ' + t5.ProviderCity + ')'),cast(t1.Newvalue as varchar))  ELSE coalesce(t3.label, cast(t1.NewValue as varchar)) END as [New Value]   
CASE WHEN t1.Changedfrom ='Upload' THEN 'UPLOAD' ELSE 'manual' END AS [Upload/Manual]   
FROM tblFieldChanges t1   
LEFT JOIN tblReferenceData t2 on t1.oldvalue=cast(t2.id as varchar)   
LEFT JOIN tblReferenceData t3 on t1.newValue=cast(t3.id as varchar)   
left join tblProviders t4 on t1.oldvalue = cast(t4.ProviderID as varchar)  
left join tblProviders t5 on t1.NewValue = cast(t5.ProviderID as varchar)  
WHERE TblName = 'tblClients' AND PKID = 8558
```

My tblFieldChanges tables looks like this...

[image]
This tables contains data from field changes that had occurred on update, so a sample data might look like this...

```
ID    tblName    FldName    PKID    Oldvalue   NewValue   ChangedOn   
17    tblClients Cost       19      1774.14    1775.19    7/21/2017 8:45am
```

The other table names, mainly tblReferenceData and tblProviders both have an ID and a text Value that I grab (especially tblReferenceData). Anyone know why I might be getting an error. It seems that it doesn't only error out on a number as is the case in the error, but also, if I have a text value such as city (San Francisco) I get a similar error stating that Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'San Francisco' to data type int.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Create a test case, that is remove everything until you have a minimal version. While you are at it, you probably should also replace pictures with text.

Comment: Poor table design... Re-design, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Error seems pretty obvious. `1774.14` is not a valid integer, but you are comparing it to an integer (1000). SQL is doing an implicit conversion. Change your column types to be correct (Decimal(19,2) for example) or cast your varchar oldvalue as decimal, which will allow you to do the comparison. I would highly recommend fixing the column type as opposed to casting, but it's your funeral!

Comment: @JacobH but i'm only comparing it if the fldName is specific in this cast LastKnownProvider. I can't have it as decimal because oldValue and newValue fields have a variety of different data, from simple textValues to numbers and dates. I'm not really doing anything with it other than dumping the data in a Grid to show the user what changes have been made to a particular client

Comment: Look at your query. You are comparing it to the exact integer 1000.

Comment: Can `OldValue` and `NewValue` be not a number?

Comment: They cannot have decimals if you want to do an integer comparison. "Number" is not a type in SQL-Server.

Comment: @JacobH i know I meant to say INT. The thing is I'm trying to store all types of values in teh oldValue and newValue  fields

Comment: Yes, and that is a terrible idea for reasons you are finding out right now.

Comment: So why are you using varchar, not numeric type?

Comment: @rokuto because if i have a datatype as Numeric I can't enter varchar values. I need to have a versatile field, so I need to be able to store any type of datatype value...that's the reason

Comment: The second answer I gave should fix your issue then (using the string value instead of a numeric comparison). But still... this is not a good practice and I would only do it if I had no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP has stated that the data type cannot be changed. Here is the solution by casting the OldValue and NewValue values to decimal before doing a comparison:

```
SELECT t1.changedon as [Changed On], t1.fldname as [Field Name],   
CASE WHEN (t1.Fldname='LastKnownProvider' and CAST(t1.oldValue AS DECIMAL(19,2)) > 1000) THEN coalesce((t4.ProviderName + ' (' + t4.ProviderAddress + ', ' + t4.ProviderCity + ')'),cast(t1.oldvalue as varchar))  ELSE coalesce(t2.label,cast(t1.oldvalue as varchar)) END as [Old Value],   
CASE WHEN (t1.Fldname='LastKnownProvider' and CAST(t1.newValue AS DECIMAL(19,2))  > 1000) THEN coalesce((t5.ProviderName + ' (' + t5.ProviderAddress + ', ' + t5.ProviderCity + ')'),cast(t1.Newvalue as varchar))  ELSE coalesce(t3.label, cast(t1.NewValue as varchar)) END as [New Value]   
CASE WHEN t1.Changedfrom ='Upload' THEN 'UPLOAD' ELSE 'manual' END AS [Upload/Manual]   
FROM tblFieldChanges t1   
LEFT JOIN tblReferenceData t2 on t1.oldvalue=cast(t2.id as varchar)   
LEFT JOIN tblReferenceData t3 on t1.newValue=cast(t3.id as varchar)   
left join tblProviders t4 on t1.oldvalue = cast(t4.ProviderID as varchar)  
left join tblProviders t5 on t1.NewValue = cast(t5.ProviderID as varchar)  
WHERE TblName = 'tblClients' AND PKID = 8558
```

This can also be done by using a string comparison, but this is a very bad practice:

`t1.oldValue > '1000'`